# Install matching Linux header files after Linux kernel upgrade

Tags: linux-kernel, upgrade, header-file

I recently upgraded my Linux kernel from 4.19.20 to 5.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64.

`sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.5.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 is already the newest version (5.5.17-1~bpo10+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`ls -l /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)` gives me:

```
total 1432
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    4096  6月 10 23:54 arch
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096  6月 10 23:54 include
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      61  4月 23 23:15 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1453072  4月 23 23:15 Module.symvers
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34  4月 23 23:15 scripts -> ../../lib/linux-kbuild-5.5/scripts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32  4月 23 23:15 tools -> ../../lib/linux-kbuild-5.5/tools
```

Does this mean that the matching Linux header files have been installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this means the headers have been installed.

See also the `build` and `source` symlinks in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` (those are the important locations).

Comment: Thanks. Is installing the matching Linux header files after a kernel upgrade necessary? I am trying to install a new NVIDIA driver but it will not load.

Comment: In most cases it isn’t, but you do need them for the NVIDIA driver. Feel free to [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with details of what you’ve tried and the errors you’re getting with the NVIDIA driver!